# Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns' in pg/lib

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, sequelize.js

I did create-react-app and also installed sequelize and pg. But when I do npm start, I get the following error -

---

./node_modules/pg/lib/connection-parameters.js

### Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/Users/vedant/Web Dev/device_psql/node_modules/pg/lib'

Here is the App.js file -

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres', 'postgres', 'password', {
host: 'localhost',
dialect: 'postgres',

pool: {
  max: 5,
  min: 0,
  acquire: 30000,
  idle: 10000
},

// http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators
operatorsAliases: false
});

class App extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <div >
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

---

Also, in the package.json file, I have sequelize and pg. What could be the problem? I have tried to delete the node_modules folder and doing npm install, but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check your versions of Sequelize and pg, I remember having some trouble with pg@7 being incompatible with a previous version of sequelize

Answer (score 34):

This is happening because one of your packages uses JavaScript promises, which depend on the `dns` module, which is only available in Node.js (server-side) and not when your code  runs in the browser. Though the implementation depends on it, it does not require it to work, so you can solve the problem by faking the existence of the `dns` module.

To do so, follow these steps:

Create a folder `/src/mock/dns`. Inside this folder, create a file `index.js` containing:

```
module.exports = {}; 
module.exports.default = {};
```

Also inside this folder, create a file `package.json` containing:

```
{ 
  "name": "dns", 
  "version": "3.1.0", 
  "private": true 
}
```

In your root `package.json`, add the following line to `dependencies`:

```
"dns": "file:./src/mock/dns"
```

Run `npm install` to install the fake dependency, then restart your React project with `npm start`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info Alexander. I was able to solve the problem. I was accessing Postgres using Sequelize from React although it can only be accessed via back-end (in this case Node).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to use Nodemailer inside of Cloudflare Workers.

I was getting the following error with the Nodemailer package:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '~/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport'
```

When I researched the error, I found that Webpack is trying to bundle things for the client that can only be used in the server. See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/744.

The solution was to add the [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) property to my `webpack.config.js` file and include all the modules that cannot be resolved by Webpack. See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/744#issuecomment-320437402.

My `webpack.config.js` file now looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  target: "webworker",
  entry: "./index.js",
  externals: [
    "child_process",
    "dns",
    "fs",
    "net",
    "tls",
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I discovered some new information that deals with Cloudflare Workers specifically, but that gets away from the original topic. So I created a new post: [Cloudflare Workers: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '~/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64078248/cloudflare-workers-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-child-process-in/64078249#64078249)
.

Answer (score 0):

Importing fetch at the top of the file solved the issue for me.

```react
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

Don't forget to install it before: [Install node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Answer (score 0):

You can encounter this if you try to use pg in code that will run on the browser, such as in an `onSubmit` or `onClick` handler. The obtuse error messages are from webpack trying to reference symbols that are stripped from the browser-destined output.

To resolve the problem, ensure that you make database queries and updates via REST API handlers or other server-side code.