# Cloudflare Workers: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '~/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport'

Tags: serverless, cloudflare-workers

I was getting the following error with the Nodemailer package in a Cloudflare Worker and wanted to document what I found.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '~/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport'
```

Answer (score 3):

While developing with Cloudflare Workers, I was getting the following error with the Nodemailer package:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '~/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport'
```

When I researched the error, I found that Webpack is trying to bundle things for the client that can only be used in the server. See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/744.

One possible solution was to add the [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) property to a [custom `webpack.config.js` file for my Worker](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/cli-wrangler/webpack) and include all the modules that cannot be resolved by Webpack. See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/744#issuecomment-320437402.

So my `webpack.config.js` file would look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  target: "webworker",
  entry: "./index.js",
  externals: [
    "child_process",
    "dns",
    "fs",
    "net",
    "tls",
  ]
}
```

However, I found out that you can't use packages like Nodemailer in a Cloudflare Worker. Cloudflare Workers do not have a Node environment, so you can't use Node packages like you would in a server-side platform that has a Node environment. So the Webpack configurations above won't do you much good anyway because you still can't use Nodemailer to send email from a Cloudflare Worker. However, there are often alternative ways to use Node packages or other Node features in a Cloudflare Worker. For example, in order to send email from a Worker you have to use a REST API instead of a Node package:

- [Sending e-mails from Cloudflare Workers](https://dev.to/gzuidhof/sending-e-mails-from-cloudflare-workers-2abl)
- [Did anyone get @sendgrid/email to work on workers?](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/did-anyone-get-sendgrid-email-to-work-on-workers/188366)